# Run 2 '.move' SKActions simultaneously

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a confetti implementation using `SKSpriteNode` and `SKAction`.

**Desired behavior:**
The confetti should *sway back and forth* while also falling down.

**Actual behavior:**
The confetti falls down -- but does not sway back and forth.

**What I've tried:** Putting the two actions into a `group`, like this:

```
            let x = MainData.screenWidth*CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
            let testNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: MainData.confettiTexture)
            let gravityAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: -100.0), duration: 5.0)
            let swaySequence = SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -MainData.screenWidth*0.2, dy: 0.0), duration: 0.5),
                SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: MainData.screenWidth*0.2, dy: 0.0), duration: 0.5)
            ])
            let swayInfinitely = SKAction.repeatForever(swaySequence)
            let group = SKAction.group([
                swayInfinitely,
                gravityAction
            ])
            
            gravityAction.timingMode = .easeIn
            
            testNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: MainData.screenHeight)
            testNode.size = CGSize(width: MainData.screenWidth*0.05, height: MainData.screenWidth*0.05)
            
            testNode.run(group)
```

**My theory:**
I'm guessing that this problem is happening because I'm trying to use `move(to:duration:)` and `move(by:duration:)` at the same time, thus supplying conflicting x-axis values.

So, how can I get my confetti to sway back and forth while also falling down? What am I doing wrong/not understanding about `SKAction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the confetti nodes as child nodes of a parent SKNode. Have the parent node run the gravity action, and the confetti nodes run the sway one.